# Rspec and Chrome/headless flag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, rspec, capybara

I've got headless Chrome and Chrome working for my Rspec tests. I want a flag to switch between the two so I can see the tests happen when I want and hide them when I don't. How can I implement something like:

```
rspec --headless
```

Right now I just have this secret tied to a `.env` var:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = Rails.application.secrets.headless ? :headless_chrome : :chrome
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, overriding the env var works so that's something.

```
HEADLESS=true rspec
```

Comment: Just a note for anyone who finds this now. This apparently only works with Rails >= 5.1, not on Rails 5.0.

Answer (score 3):

in your rails_helper.rb you should create a statement like that:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:each) do
    if  ENV['HEADLESS'] == 'true'
      Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome_headless
    else
      Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
    end
  end
end
```

then send a variable when running specs

```
$ HEADLESS=true rspec ./spec/features
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I personally use this code to register driver:

```
Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        ('headless' if ENV.fetch('HEADLESS', '1') == '1')
      ].compact
    }   
  )

  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: capabilities
  )
end
```

then in `.env` you can set the variable to be HEADLESS or not by default and then if you want to overwrite it just type `HEADLESS=0 rspec`

Comment: Not sure how that's different to what I wrote.